# Connecting network devices on different floors

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

As the title suggests, i need help connecting network devices which reside on different floors within our house. The scenario is as follows:
The PC i need to connect is in the bottom floor (1F). Our router with the only internet connection however, resides in the 3rd floor (3F). I now need to somehow connect my PC to this router. I do not have an internet connection available in the bottom floor.
Right now, the two are connected like this:
Router --> Ethernet --> PowerLAN/DLAN --> Ethernet --> PC, however, this type of connection is insufficient for my needs as i lose about 2/3rds of my (already slim) available bandwidth. 
Connecting them via a long LAN cable is not an option unfortunately.
I've thought about using special parabolic antenna to connect them, like this:
Router --> Ethernet --> Antenna --> Antenna ---> Ethernet ---> PC.
And then mount these antenna outside my house and align them correctly.

Is there any useful input perhaps? I'm not quite sure which parts to use to accomplish this task.

Comment: Having a wifi router and a repeater on each floor might work.  When you say the home owner is against a LAN cable, is it they don't a cable to trip on, or etc, running across the floor OR they don't want to open the walls and drill OR both?

Comment: You might be able to install line filters to help eliminate electrical noises on the circuits where the outlet based LAN things are located. Also which LAN over power devices did you buy, they are not all equally built.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Homeplug-Noise-Filter-Powerline-Networks/dp/B004PEIFZO/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8

Comment: I tried the wifi repeaters (albeit with cheap models), which was atrocious. Even worse than with PowerLAN. Will try better models friday tho.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Powerline-Pass-through-2000Mbps-TL-PA9020P-KIT/dp/B01H74VKZU/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=sl1&tag=hsi20-20&linkId=70da2e2f554593a75507cf619d34590d      At least 5 sites have given this high mark 4+ stars

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a definite answer to this. Here are some things I'd look into:

- Using a long etehrnet LAN cable *is* the best solution in terms of speed and reliability. You didn't say *why* it's not an option; in my experience, it's possible to deploy a long ethernet cable even without a lot of drilling if you stick to stranded cable (patch cable) instead of solid core (better bend radius). That works even in stair cases.
- You didn't give details about the PowerLAN/DLAN in use, e.g. actual measurement of bandwidth adapter-to-adapter, and how this compares to your internet bandwidth. It's easy to make mistakes with PowerLAN, e.g. putting the adapters on a distributor socket instead of a wall socket, or putting both adapters on different phases without a good phase-to-phase communication somewhere. So it might be worth trying to optimize the PowerLAN connection - experiment a bit, and *measure* raw throughput.
- For the router/antenna solution, again the information about the desireable bandwidth is missing (is 802.11n (2.4 Ghz) enough? Do you need 802.11ac (5 Ghz)? etc.). It's perfectly possible to grab some cheap routers with detachable antennas, e.g. TP-Link, flash OpenWRT on them, and make your own [cantenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantenna). Then set up some [mesh mode](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/mesh.80211s), and you're good. Getting the antennas outside is more tricky (antenna cable shouldn't be too long, drilling holes to the outside requires special measures to isolate them), as is getting the router+antenna ensemble (needs extra waterproof case for protection).
- An alternative to "make it yourself" would be to buy a more expensive router that's already tailor-made for the outside, with direction antenna(s), e.g. the TP-Link CPE 210/220 (2.4 Ghz) or CPE 510/520 (5 Ghz), or a Ubiquity Nanostation, etc. Check the market, there are probably many more devices like this.

**Edit**

(In general, please edit your question with further information, don't put it in comments).

> Laying a LAN cable is not possible simply because the homeowner doesnt want it.

Depending on the laws of the country you are in, he may have to tolerate a non-permanent installation, though. But if course angering the homeowner is a slippery slope.

> Now that i think about, same probably applies to the antennas.

If I was the homeowner, I'd frown a lot more on an exterior installation (drilling through outer walls) compare to interior ones, because the exterior ones *really* can be a PITA.

That leaves either PowerLAN, or WLAN between two interior routers. To test: What PowerLAN bandwidth do you get if you put the adapters next to each other? On the same floor? Any sockets/socket combinations that are particularly bad or good? As I said, experiment. For WLAN: what signal strength and bandwidth do you get for an ordinary AP on one floor, and a station on the other?

(And I wouldn't call 50 MBit/s internet bandwidth "already slim"; there's quite a few households here in Germany outside bigger towns who'd be happy to get this much ...)

Comment: Firstl, thank you for taking your time to answer.

Comment: -Laying a LAN cable is not possible simply because the homeowner doesnt want it. Now that i think about, same probably applies to the antennas.

Comment: -My current available total bandwidth is 50MBit/s. Bandwidth of my PowerLAN setup ranges, depending on the power sockets used, between 6 and at MAX 18MBit/s. Thats just the maximum i was able to get out with any combination. And also sorry for posting in multiple comments, im on my phone and managed to confuse "confirm" with "enter".

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it done, but it's not my first preference, however it might work within your constraints.  Running an ethernet cable through your furnace ducting could work, as it's not drilling holes or doing anything permanent to the building.

I would suggest running the cable through the return air (cold) ducting, rather than the forced air (hot) side.  There might not be enough heat to matter on the hot side, but that's just something I'd rather not risk, if it was up to me.

You'll have to figure out what is the return air vs. forced air, but that can be as simple as holding your hand up to the vent while the furnace/AC is running.

You may need to have the cable a little taut to prevent banging against the side of the ducting while air is moving, or it may need slack to lay down.  That's just something you're going to have to figure out what works best in your case, if you use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on reading reviews, and product views and other research.

1. Figure out which outlets are on which circuit breakers.
2. Mark the ones with either a network sender or receiver on them with pen or sticker for reference.
3. Get line filters/conditioners that completely block noise for other devices plugged into the same circuit as a sender **or** receiver.  So they will prevent the device from adding to the AC line noise.
4. You may want to start unplugging devices and compare speeds to see if certain devices cause speed drop.  You may have to unplug the network powerline adapter and plug it back in cause a re-sync.
5. If power line conditioners/filters are not enough try a UPS which uses the outlet to charge batteries and then all devices run from power derived from the battery.  The signal should be much cleaner.  APC makes a decent UPS.

   The goal here is to prevent ANY device which is NOT a power line network adapter from adding to your line noise.  Also adding a whole house line noise conditioner to the electrical panel to block noise from other people's houses and devices.